# Color gradient in raster symbology using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, symbology, color

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.8. I have a raster, shown below, whose data I would like to show in a smooth, detailed manner, like in the second raster shown. I recognize that the second raster has a much smaller range (the first one has a range of about 713-1363, while the second has a range of 1-353).

Is there a way for me to show the detail in the first raster?

[image: The blocky, larger-ranged raster]

[image: The smooth, detailed raster, which has a range of 1-353]

Answer (score 0):

You could change the symbology settings of your raster. It seems you are currently using stretch as for symbolization, but you could change to "classify" (see image) and manually change the color ranges. In that way, you have much more control over the color transition.

[image]